# Create VM in Microsoft Azure from custom image without public IP

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, azure-cli, azure-virtual-network

I'm trying to create 100 VM using azure-cli from custom image without public IP address.
The VM will connect between them with load balancer.

The VM are creating using this command:

```
az vm create --resource-group myresourcegroup --availability-set my_as --name VMTestAS --image MyImage --public-ip-address none --admin-username azureuser --size Standard_F4S --no-wait --ssh-key-value my_key
```

Comment: arm template can achieve that easily, not sure about cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use CLI 2.0 to create Azure VM without public IP address, like this:

```
az vm create -n MyVm -g MyResourceGroup --public-ip-address ""
```

> --public-ip-address
>   Name of the public IP address when creating one (default) or referencing an existing one. Can also reference an
>   existing public IP by ID or specify "" for None.

More information about Azure CLI 2.0 to create Azure VM, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/vm#create).

Here is the result:

```
C:\Users\user>az vm create -n MyVm -g vm  --public-ip-address "" --image myimage
{
  "fqdns": "",
  "id": "/subscriptions/5384xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0361e29axxxx/resourceGroups/vm/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/MyVm",
  "location": "southcentralus",
  "macAddress": "00-0D-3A-73-F9-95",
  "powerState": "VM running",
  "privateIpAddress": "10.0.0.6",
  "publicIpAddress": "",
  "resourceGroup": "vm"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For `--public-ip-address ""` there should be space between quotes otherwise it will fail as it expects a parameter.